# Data modelling my store in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, data-modeling

Consider this:

I have an application that is going to end up being pretty large. It is a dashboard which will give you access to various utilities, one of which being a todo app.

If I was just going to build just a todo app, then my state object would look like so:

`{ todos:[], completed:false, todoInput:''};`

`todoInput` would be tied to a form field and and upon clicking add, it would alter the `todos` array and toggle the `completed` field. So my `combineReducers()` function would look like this.

`combineReducers({todos,completed,todoInput});`

This would make sense because all the state is relevant to the todo App because there is JUST a todo app.

Now because I am building a much more complicated application which also has a todo app, this is how my state would potentially look like:

```
{
    otherState:'',evenMoreState:[]',evenMore:{},

    todo:{ todos:[], completed:false, todoInput:''}
}
```

As you can see I have separated todos into a separate object now, so it is encapsulated and more organised. So I have 2 questions.

1) Is this a good idea? It seems like the logical move because my application will grow in size and I don't want all the pieces of state floating around as properties to the main state object. Have I gone about this correctly?

2) My combine reducers (as far as I know) cannot take a nested object. So it will now look like this.

`combineReducers({ otherState,evenMoreState,evenMore,todo})`

so now my reducer compositions will have to be done inside the reducer which handles the todo state. Is there a better/different way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely on the right track.  It's also worth noting that you can use `combineReducers` multiple times, such as:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    otherState : otherStateReducer,
    todos : combineReducers({
        todos : todosReducer,
        completed : todosCompletedReducer,
        todoInput : todoInputReducer
    })
```

The overall `todos` section could be be defined separately, and imported and referenced in the top-level `combineReducers` call if desired.
    });

You may want to read through the [Redux docs section on "Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) for more information on ways to organize reducer logic, as well as the [Redux FAQ on organizing nested state](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data).  In addition, the [Redux Techniques](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md) and [Redux Architecture](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-architecture.md) sections of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links) have links to a variety of articles about building real-world Redux applications.

Comment: ahh thanks for that repo (will be digging through it!) and the second call to combineReducers was precisely what I was looking for.